# Can't reach guests from host and vice versa in Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v

I'm configuring a Hyper-V server (2008 R2) with two NICs. I'm trying to follow the MS best practice advice of leaving one NIC for the host OS. NIC #1 is used for the OS and has no associated virtual network. NIC #2 has a virtual network with "Allow management operating system to share this network adapter" unchecked. Both NICs are attached to the same physical switch.

From other PCs in the network, I can reach both the host and the guests without issue. However, between the host and the guests there is no connectivity.

Where should I begin to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've since managed to solve the problem. I doubt that anyone else is dumb enough to make the same mistake, but I'll leave the answer here where it might at least give someone a good laugh.

Firstly, the "without issue" above wasn't entirely true - there were network dropouts and near-dropouts every now and then, Remote Desktop would stall, Hyper-V migrations would fail halfway, etc. I started digging through the system log and I noticed a lot of warnings about MAC addresses failing to register as they were already being used for Hyper-V.

I then remembered that I'd cannibalized one of the network cards in the host from an old server that was now running as a VM. I checked and sure enough, the P2V process had kept the old MAC address. For good measure, the MAC of the *other* gbit NIC in the box was used for another VM. So both of the NICs had MAC address conflicts with VMs running on the same machine...

I changed the MAC addresses of both affected VMs to "dynamic" and everything is working perfectly.